# Specify Huber loss epsilon parameter in sklearn GradientBoostingRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor` [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html) and one of the options is to set the loss function to `Huber`.
The `Huber` method itself [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.HuberRegressor.html), has a parameter `epsilon` to specify the robustness to outliers.

Is it not possible to set the `epsilon` parameter when using the ensemble method? e.g.

```
from sklearn import ensemble
params = {'n_estimators': 300, 'max_depth': 3, 'min_samples_split': 2,
          'learning_rate': 0.01, 'loss': 'huber', 'epsilon':1.0, 'alpha':.5, 'criterion':'mse', }
clf = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)
```

gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-875d10cdac68>", line 3, in <module>
    clf = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'epsilon'
```

Even this section [1.11.4.5.1. Loss Functions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#loss-functions) says to use `alpha` to control the robustness to outliers, but this is different from  `epsilon`...

Comment: `HuberLossFunction` as [defined here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55bf5d9/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py#L564) is different from `HuberRegressor`. So I am afraid you cannot do that in sklearn